# How to compare my build folder(local) with s3 bucket folder and if both folders are identical then copy step will not perform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to copy data from my build folder to s3 bucket only if there is any changes AND if build folder is identically same with the s3 folder then copy step will not perform.

```
FROM node:10
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
RUN pip3 install awscli
RUN echo "data copy to s3 folder started..."
RUN aws s3 cp . s3://bucket_name/b1  --recursive
```

Comment: just use [sync](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html), in place of `cp`, should be enough.

Comment: sometime my folder will change in that case sync will copy data there ?

Comment: yes, unless i misunderstand the issue here. From docs: Recursively copies **new and updated** files from the source directory to the destination.